# Riesz representation theorem on dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

The Riesz representation theorem on Hilbert spaces is well known, It asserts we can represent a bounded linear function on a Hilbert space $H$ with an inner product on $H$ and vice-versa.

> **My question:** Given an inner product in $H^*$, say $(a,b)_{H^*}$, can I write it as $$(a,b)_{H^*} = \langle a, f \rangle_{H^*, H}$$ where $f \in H$? This is the RRT applied to the Hilbert space $H^*$ with its dual $H$. I think it works but I never saw it so I should get it clarified.

Comment: How the inner product is given?

Comment: @Berci I guess you pull back the inner product to one on $H$ by using Riesz map.

Comment: In that case, it holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for an *arbitrary* inner product on $X:=H^*$ it is not going to work, since then $X^*$ *need not* be isomorphic to $H$.

On the other hand, the Riesz representation gives a linear isomorphism $H\to H^*$, and *if* the inner product is defined via this isomorphism, i.e. if 
$$(\langle x,-\rangle,\langle y,-\rangle)_{H^*}=\langle x,y\rangle_{H} $$
for all $x,y\in H, \ f\in H^*$, then your claim is valid:

Let $a,b\in H^*$ then $a=\langle x,-\rangle$ and $b=\langle y,-\rangle$ for some $y\in H$ by Riesz representation, and $a(y)=\langle x,y\rangle$ so we have
$$(a,b)_{H^*} = (a,\langle y,-\rangle)=a(y)=\langle a,y\rangle_{H^*,H}\ .$$

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work for arbitrary inner products? Since $H$ and $H*$ are Hilbert, they're reflexive so $H = H^{**}$

Comment: 1. How do you know $H^*$ will be Hilbert space with that *arbitrary* inner product? In general, it can have nothing common with $H$ or $H^*$, just the underlying vector space structure.. Probably *if* the generated norm is equivalent to the operator norm in $H^*$..

Comment: Ok. How about if $H^*$ is given an IP that makes it Hilbert, not necessarily the Riesz map though?

Comment: By pulling back the IP to $H$ (via the Riesz map), we get another IP on $H$, so you could start considering what connection is needed between $2$ inner products on the same vector space $H$ such that their duals are the same. Maybe, if they generate *equivalent norms* it's enough..